# Question about the minimum value of $2^{\sin^2a}+2^{\cos^2a}$.

Tags: trigonometry

How to find the minimum value of

> $$2^{\sin^2a}+2^{\cos^2a}$$

I don't understand how to start the sum.

Comment: what sum? Also If you aren't going to tex at least use parentheses. It's difficult to tell what function you want the minimum of.

Comment: $2^{\sin^2a}+2^{\cos^2a} \ge 2\sqrt2$

Answer (score 0, accepted):

We have $(x-y)^2 \geq 0 \iff x^2 + y^2 \geq 2xy$. Now let $x^2=2^{\sin^2 a}$ and $y^2=2^{\cos^2 a}$ then $$2^{\sin^2 a} + 2^{\cos^2 a} \geq 2\sqrt{2^{\sin^2 +\cos^2 a}} = 2\sqrt{2}.$$

Equality occurs at $x=y$.

Comment: Thanx for your help

Answer (score 1):

$2^{sin^{2}a}\cdot 2^{cos^{2}a} = 2$

so

$2^{sin^{2}a} +  2^{cos^{2}a} \geq  2\cdot \sqrt{2}$